# how to resize a small image from a server (android)

Tags: android, image, google-app-engine, server

I'm sending a small image to my appengine server. the original size of the image is 1024X782

now i'm compressing it to 12X9 size, since i need to save it on the server (since its appengine server - im limited to 1500 chars with 12X9 i have about 1200 chars). Ive tried to decript it but its so small and blurry you can't really see it. so how do i do it??

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
decodedByte.createScaledBitmap(decodedByte,1092, 782, true); // not working
```

My compressing image thing:

```
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            bm = decodeUri(uri_try);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 6;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);

}
```

its seems that i have the decode here, but this is what im sending to the server and i don't know the scaling as well.

anyone got idea how should i do it?

Comment: 'with 12X9 i have about 1200 chars'. ??? Please show your calculation. Why are you not talking about bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually resize an image to full details after scaling it down. And a 12x9 image is really unusable.
Your "compression" algorithm doesn't actually compress anything. It isn't a reversible action like archiving a file, where data size is reduced without losing any information. All your code does is remove some of the pixels from your image. And once removed, they're gone for good.

Regarding the limitation on the appengine server, I don't really know much about it, but it seems to apply only to strings. If there is a limitation for other types of data you should consider not sending it.
But if you really must send the image and you want to keep the resolution and you still encounter the data limitation, you could do the following thing: after compressing the bitmap and obtaining the byte array from the output stream, you could split it into smaller chunks. You could then encode each chunk and send them one by one and then reverse the process on the other side (decode the strings, obtain byte arrays, put them back together and creating a new bitmap from the resulted byte array).

I'm sure there is a better solution, but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the problem is that you are trying to store the image as string on appengine data store and you are running into length limitation. I believe if you  use BlobProperty to store  the image you will not run into this trouble.